# Optimize code to not start from 1 every time it goes through for loop

Tags: c

I got this homework and I was thinking how to optimize it if possible.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
int funk(n){
    int a=1,b=1,j,i,flag=0;
    for(a=1;a<n;a++){
        for(b=1;b<n;b++){
            if((pow(a,2)*b)-a+b+(a*pow(b,2))==n){    
                for(i=1;i<a;i++){
                    for(j=i;j<a;j++){
                        if(a%i==0 && a%j==0 && b%(i+j)==0){
                                printf("For n= %d equation has solutions %d and %d \n",n,a,b);
                                flag = 1;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==2){
        printf("For n= %d equation has no solution \n",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    int n,i;
    printf("Input n ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
        funk(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking about for loops in `funk()` so when I enter a `n` in `main()` and call for `funk()` and for example n is 10000 time for execution is long because it starts from 1 for every try.

Comment: Step 1: Understand what it does.

Comment: What you want is that for different execution of program the n should start from different number as it has already calculate values for previous input?

Comment: `int funk(n) { }` n is what? Assuming it's a typo and should be `int funk(int n)` it is overkill using `pow` to calculate a square, and you end up comparing `double` with `int`.

Comment: Aside as a matter of style, `i<=n` is more readable by humans than `i<n+1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I found it more easy to work with n+1 
N is integer you pass to function and it needs to return all solutions to equation that satisfies condition that sum of dividers of a should divide b.

Comment: `if(flag==2)` so where is `flag` set to 2. Please post your exact code, that's the second typo.

Comment: @WeatherVane in original flag is if(flag==0)

Answer (score 0):

So *don't* let it start all over again every time. You don't need the loop in main and you can change func to:

```
int funk(n){
    int a=1,b=1,j,i,flag=0;
    for(a=1;a<n;a++){
        int n2= a;
        for(b=1;b<n2;b++){
            if((pow(a,2)*b)-a+b+(a*pow(b,2))==n2){
```

and call it like

```
funk(n+1);
```